# Is Computer Modern 12 pt an exact scaled version of 10 pt? If not, how to scale?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern

I have always felt that the 10 pt font looks nicer than 12 pt, either in PDF or printed. The 12 pt looks taller (in other words the 10pt looks fatter).

My questions are:

1. Is the 12 pt font a scaled version of the 10 pt one?
2. If not, then how can we create a new 12 pt font by scaling the 10 pt one (in both LaTeX and XeLaTex)? It seems that by doing so we'll obtain a thicker version of the 12pt font.

Comment: Just in case you want a thicker version of the computer modern fonts, you can take a look at the mlmodern and newcomputermodern (book weight) fonts. these are clones of computer modern, but heavier. the newcomputermodern fonts have full unicode coverage, plus some additional symbols.

Comment: And no, the CM 12pt fonts are not simply scaled versions. Fonts generally become thinner and squished in the vertical direction as the point size increases. I don't know about pdflatex, but you can simply pass the scaled option to the `\setmainfont` command with fontspec.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Thanks a lot! `newcomputermodern` looks very promising. However I would still like to obtain an answer for my second question, just to have an additional option.

Comment: The package relsize might be of use, although I have not tested the output. https://ctan.org/pkg/relsize?lang=en

Comment: If you are using lualatex or xelatex, with `fontspec` package, then the Latin Modern fonts should be used instead of Computer Modern. Your question applies to these fonts, as well.

Comment: @rallg Indeed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Look at the history of the Computer Modern typeface - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern and Knuth, D. E. (1986). Computer Modern Typefaces.  Addison-Wesley Publishing Company.  These typefaces have a remarkable longevity for something created in the late 1970s.

Comment: @cfr Sorry I didn't mean to show the answer to the question. I wanted to show the final results that confirm my intuition about the shape of the scaled font. The code included was for the purpose of reproducing the screenshot.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I've deleted the "Update" part to avoid any confusions.

Comment: @f10w  Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Computer modern fonts were generated by Metafont to many sizes designed ideally for such size (i.e. optical sizes). For example, Coputer Modern Roman was generated to cmr5, cmr6, cmr7, cmr8, cmr9, cmr10, cmr12, cmr17.

You should use cmr10 for 10pt size or cmr12 for 12pt size. But TeX allows geometrical scaling too (of course) using "at parameter" of the `\font` primitive.

```
\font\fa=cmr10
\font\fb=cmr12
\font\fc=cmr10 at12pt

\fa Here is 10pt size font cmr10.
\fb Here is 12pt size font cmr12.
\fc Here is 12pt size font cmr10.
```

Comment: Great answer!!! Thank you so much! Would it be possible to add a solution for Latin Modern as well please?

Comment: @f10w Note that you probably don't want to use this as a *solution* in LaTeX, even though it demonstrates the differences nicely.

Comment: wipet as you know this is simply wrong/confusing for latex (which leads to the @f10w asking a followup question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696628/how-to-set-the-document-to-use-a-new-font-defined-by-the-font-command) No objection to a plain/primitive answer here but as the OP specified latex in the question you could have mentioned that fonts declared this way will not interact with the latex font mechanisms.

Comment: The question didn't mention LaTeX. If somebody have a LaTeX-dependent answer, he/she can add such an answer here.

Comment: The question specifies 'LaTeX and XeLaTeX'. Please make the limitations of this answer clear.

Comment: @cfr and david-carlisle: Thank you very much for the clarification! Is there a better solution please?

Comment: (tagging @david-carlisle)

Comment: @f10w Choose one of the other fonts people have suggested, which have LaTeX support or can be used with `fontspec`. Or switch to plain TeX. Technically, you could create a LaTeX font, but it would inherit almost all the limitations of the original TeX fonts. It would be (1) a lot of work with (2) a steep learning curve and (3) an unsatisfactory result. What don't you like about newcomputermodern, for example? Or tell us what you especially like about cm10 scaled and we can try to suggest something.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your informative comment. Actually I am pleased with `newcomputermodern`, so I'm no longer looking for the above alternative.