# How to set the document to use a new font defined by the \font command?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have defined a new font with the following command: `\font\cmtwelve=cmr10 at12pt` (credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696568/24048).

Now my question is how to use this font in my document, in the same spirit as using `\setmainfont{\cmtwelve}` from `fontspec`. I tried `\setmainfont{\cmtwelve}` but it didn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tldr; You think you want to do this, but, trust me, you don't. This is not a couple of lines of code and you're done.

Comment: don't use \font in latex. that is the tex primitive, if you drop to that level you undo all latex font handling

Comment: apart from the syntax, you do not want to use cmr10 in lluaatex, it is a 7 bit font with just 128 characters not in unicode order so would not work well with any luatex commands6

Comment: @cfr and david-carlisle: Thanks for your comments. I just wanted to have an alternative to cmr12, but I think I should abandon this option as you both have pointed out.

Comment: (cc @david-carlisle)

Comment: If you're happy with `newcomputermodern` (per your reply to my comment on wipet's answer), do you want me to write an answer suggesting that?

Comment: @cfr Thanks but that doesn't seem to be relevant to the above question and thus is not really an answer. `newcomputermodern` was suggested to me in the other question.

Comment: Well, it wasn't an answer to that question either. Should we close this question? There isn't an answer to this question. The best response is 'don't do that', as we've already explained. That was also the best response to the second part of your other question.

Comment: @cfr Indeed, that's why I think it was not posted as an answer to my other question. Would it be possible to post an answer to the current question explaining in some detail why one shouldn't do what I asked? That would be helpful to many inexperienced users like me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @f10w That *is* why it was not posted as answer to your other question ;). It's also why it was not posted as an answer to this one w/o discussion.

Comment: In that case, surely we can find a duplicate @DavidCarlisle?